# I have spreadsheet and LINKS from google form upload files. but when I transfer data to docs using markers those links are not clickable

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs, google-forms

I have these links:

[image]

```
// var admin equals to my column links
function autoFillDoc(e) {

var prof = e.values[8];
var admin = e.values[9];
if (Service == "sccc"){

    var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById("1YssTtcnIODb42TrQAKCaNZjkNUmh1U1pxEQfrSPJ4nA");
    var templateResponseFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1-_2XTt4_26Fbs-KjduVlVaTutHsyU_33");

    var copy = templateFile.makeCopy(Service + ', ' + firstName , templateResponseFolder);
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
    var body = doc.getBody();

    body.replaceText("{{FirstName}}", firstName);
    body.replaceText("{{LastName}}", LastName);
    body.replaceText("{{BirthDate}}", birthdate);
    body.replaceText("{{Service}}", Service);
    body.replaceText("{{admin}}", admin);

    doc.saveAndClose();
}
```

how can I do to hyperlink my data from spreadsheet to google docs thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The method to set links into a Google document is `setLinkUrl()`

I cannot quite understand from your code what are the "markers" and where are the hyperlinks, but a small sample to create clickable links in Google Docs would be:

```
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  body.getParagraphs()[0].appendText("text").setLinkUrl("www.wikipedia.de");
```

Comment: {{admin}}  that's my marking to call data in the spreadsheet. but how can I  use body.getParagraphs()[0].appendText("text").setLinkUrl("www.wikipedia.de"); and transfer link to google docs